# How can I utilize ws library instead of socket.io in NestJS to consume "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"?

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs, web-development-server, ws

I'm encountering challenges while trying to consume the "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089" endpoint using ws library WebSockets in NestJS.

Despite referring to the NestJS WebSocket documentation at `https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter#ws-library` and conducting further research, I have not achieved the desired outcome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a ws client, not a server instance (what `@nestjs/platform-ws` is for). You can use the `ws` library directly to make a client by passing the URL to the `WebSocket` constructor. For more information, reference [`ws`'s docs](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#class-websocket)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, the implementation has been a success.